# Binary Search Tree remove function not working(homework)

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

For my assignment i am to implement a Binary Search Tree class, i have successfully implemented all of the methods except remove. It does work just not consistently and i cannot find the issue. Here is the code...

```
template <class T>
void binSTree<T>::remove(Node <T>* p, const T& v)
{
    // Find the item
    bool found = false;
    Node<T>* predecessor = nullptr;
    Node<T>* current = n;
    while (current != nullptr)
    {
        if (current->data == item)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            predecessor = current;
            if (item > (current->data))
                current = current->right;
            else
                current = current->left;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        return;
    }
    // CASE 1: Removing a node with a single child
    if ((current->left == nullptr && current->right != nullptr) || (current-
>left != nullptr && current->right == nullptr))
    {
        // Right Leaf Present, No Left Leaf
        if (current->left == nullptr && current->right != nullptr)
        {
            // If predecessor's left tree equals Node n
            if (predecessor->left == current)
            {
                // then predecessor's left tree becomes n's right tree
                // and delete n
                predecessor->left = current->right;
                delete current;
                current = nullptr;
            }
            // If predecessor's right tree equals Node n
            else
             {
                 // then predecessor's right tree becomes n's right tree
                way down left to locate smallest element
                    if ((current->right)->left != nullptr)
                     {
                         Node<T>* leftCurrent;
                         Node<T>* leftCurrentPred;
                        leftCurrentPred = current->right;
                        leftCurrent = (current->right)->left;
                        while (leftCurrent->left != nullptr)
                        {
                            leftCurrentPred = leftCurrent;
                            leftCurrent = leftCurrent->left;
                        }
                        current->data = leftCurrent->data;
                        delete leftCurrent;
                        leftCurrentPred->left == nullptr;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Node<T>* temp = current->right;
                        current->data = temp->data;
                        current->right = temp->right;
                        delete temp;
                    }
            }
            return;
     }

}
```

When it is used to remove multiple values from a BST this is what happens as an example...

given a tree of 50 values...

```
   1   36  104  159  183  184  198  219  220  241  287  294  304  356  369  378  380  387  394  395
 418  464  491  516  521  525  582  583  623  641  648  653  667  692  702  703  724  729  743  765
 796  802  887  897  901  909  969  971  979  992
```

after removing some values from the tree it is supposed to contain this..

```
   1   36  104  159  183  198  219  220  241  294  304  356  369  378  387  394  395  418  464  491
 516  525  582  583  623  641  648  653  692  702  703  724  729  765  796  802  887  897  909  969
 971  992
```

but this is the output i receive...

```
   1   36  104  159  183  198  219  220  241  294  304  356  369  378  387  394  395  418  464  491
 516  525    0  582  583  623  641  648  653  692  702  703  724  729  765  796  802  887  897  909
 969  971  992
```

As you can see it contains one more value than it should and also works perfectly up until the 23rd removal where it adds a 0 to the tree for some reason. After reviewing my code i cant seem to find what is causing this to happen and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Although it's HW, i'm vote up just because your clear question! keep it on and good luck!

Comment: I agree that this question is well written. Still, this site is not about code review and finding bugs. Such things are very unlikely to help other users - unless the specific bug is common.

Comment: hope you tried debugging it ?